# dticks and plotly, how to control what is shown on x axes

Tags: python, plotly

I wrote this code that shows a boxplot for every month I have data.

```py
def grafico_boxplot_precio_norm_mes(product):
    df = datos_graf_boxplot(product)
    df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
    fig = px.box(df,
            x="month",
            y="precio_norm_imp",
            color = 'tipo',
            
            labels={
                    "month": "Meses",
                    "precio_norm_imp": "Precio normalizado imputado",
                    'tipo': 'Tipo'
                },
            points = 'outliers'
            
            )

    fig.show()
```

What I have not been successful with is with what is shown on the x axis, where I need to show every month, not every two months.

Thank you!

The output of this function is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample from the official [reference](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#configuring-tick-labels) of plotly (time series data with investment data as a line graph). I forced it to change to a boxplot to match your graph image; to make the x-axis monthly, set dtick='M1'.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.box(df, x="date", y=df.columns,
              hover_data={"date": "|%B %d, %Y"},
              title='custom tick labels with ticklabelmode="period"')
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%b\n%Y",
    ticklabelmode="period")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't sure about your data, so please replace it with yours as I am using suboptimal time series data. If my answer was helpful to you, please accept my response.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a specific ticker locator to override the default set by pandas. For example, you can add the following line before `fig.show()`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
fig.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.LinearLocator(numticks=len(data)))
```

[Other Locators](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) could also work, e.g., MultipleLocator or FixedLocator.